Asus MB168B portable display
I'm testing a DisplayLink driven Asus MB168B portable display on an Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with an Intel Arc based Lenovo ThinkPad E16 Gen 2 notebook.
I have a problem when I move window on the display.
The screen is streaked.
Please see my screencast:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTjqag9Ed0U
I use display-link version 6.1.0-17.
Kernel is Linux 6.8.0-51-generic.
I tested it on a Lenovo Y520-15IKBM that has an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 and no problem with the same software versions.
How can I solve this problem?
